# Need basic loop for js to sum two fields, since they're multiple groups

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a basic loop to sum two fields. **I just get it to work for one group**, but the others remain the same. I know I need some kind of array to solve this, but I can't work it out. (*Notice, they are 50 groups in the original project, but I just added 2*) Here is the code:

HTML

```
<label>Value 1:</label><input type="text" name="value1[]" id="txtval1"><br>
<label>Value 2:</label><input type="text" name="value2[]" id="txtval2"><br>
<label>Total:</label><input type="text" name="total[]" id="txttotal"><br><br>
<label>Value 1:</label><input type="text" name="value1[]" id="txtval1"><br>
<label>Value 2:</label><input type="text" name="value2[]" id="txtval2"><br>
<label>Total:</label><input type="text" name="total[]" id="txttotal">
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Get Total</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var val1 = document.getElementById('txtval1').value;
var val2 = document.getElementById('txtval2').value;
var total = document.getElementById('txttotal');
var sum = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2);
if (val1.value!='' && val2.value!=''){
total.value='';
total.value = total.value + sum;
}
   }
</script>
```

I don't know why this doen't work on my fiddle, but does in my local machine. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neqqc/1/)

Comment: It does'nt work because you added HTML script tags inside the javascript window -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gKUh/6/)

Comment: You have same ID on two elements

Comment: exactly @HodayaShalom it had to work like that. They are originally 50 groups, but I just added a piece, for this case.

Comment: It will do you only the first, because when you write `document.getElementById` is taking the first ID appears

Comment: Exactly @HodayaShalom that's why I need an array, but I can't work it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that giving the same ID to two elements It is mistake.

You have to give a different ID for each element and pass them on for.

Look at this `fiddle`:

**http://jsfiddle.net/83m6e/**

**EDIT**: I changed the fiddle for option2:

http://jsfiddle.net/83m6e/3/

You also can put each segment into a div and then do not change the names.

Comment: Thank you @HodayaShalom I can do different ID in the HTML, with a counter in the end of the ID, I just need the name[] to remain the same to be sent through PHP. Your script loops nice.

Comment: There's is one just problem @HodayaShalom When one field is blank, I get NaN and this is not solved by the `if (val1.value != '' && val2.value != '') {...`

Comment: change to this:  `if (val1 != '' && val2 != '')`

Comment: Still NaN @HodayaShalom :/

Comment: I did it with your last fix. Thank you so much @HodayaShalom ! forgive my noob js skills

Comment: It's OK, Good luck to you @HerlandCid

Answer (score 0):

You can not add up to arrays in order to add up their elements. You must do it one by one. Try this code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction()
   {
    var count = 3;
    var val1, val2, sum;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
     val1 = document.getElementById('txtval1_' + i).value;
     val2 = document.getElementById('txtval2_' + i).value;
     sum = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2);
     document.getElementById('txttotal_' + i).value = sum;
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <label>Value 1:</label><input type="text" id="txtval1_0"><br>
  <label>Value 2:</label><input type="text" id="txtval2_0"><br>
  <label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="txttotal_0"><br><br>
  <label>Value 1:</label><input type="text" id="txtval1_1"><br>
  <label>Value 2:</label><input type="text" id="txtval2_1"><br>
  <label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="txttotal_1"><br><br>
  <label>Value 1:</label><input type="text" id="txtval1_2"><br>
  <label>Value 2:</label><input type="text" id="txtval2_2"><br>
  <label>Total:</label><input type="text" id="txttotal_2"><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Get Total</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Accepted answer is a lot like mine, I answered first.